# Map breaks if I pass lat, lng as variable

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

This is driving me nuts.  Using Google Maps v3 I am loading the map using php to determine lat long :

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = "<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $long;?>";
    console.log(latlng);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $long;?>),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas")
                                       , mapOptions);
}
```

This works fine.  However if I try to pass in the latlng var

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng),
```

the maps just shows a blue screen and is broken (no zoom or controls or anything).  The console log and source look like it is generating the parameters correctly.  Any ideas on what might be happening?

I did have `initialize()` on `body` but I moved it to the `(document).ready` in my script.  This did not seem to make any difference for this problem.

Comment: shoudn't it be `LatLng(lat, lng)` -- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $long;?>)
```

is not the same as

```
new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $long;?>")
```

The quotes mean you are passing in a string literal to the LatLng constructor, which does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
new google.maps.LatLng(12.3456, 12.3456);
```

is not the same as

```
var latlng = "12.3456,12.3456";
new google.maps.LatLng(latlng);
```

The former passes two numeric parameters into the function, which is what's expected. The latter passes one string into the function, which is an error.